# Display Text in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment, I am displaying text from my model on the screen:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
    @Model.AccountNumber
</div>
```

But I want to add a css class to this bit of text. How can I add a css class to the text? The class simply bolds the text, but I don't want to add `<strong></strong>` to all the areas I want to bold. I want to add a class, so I can change it later.

I have tried:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
     <span class="display_text">@Model.AccountNumber</span>
</div>
```

But it seems to make no difference.

My CSS:

```
.display_text{
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

I created a fiddle, and it works, so something else is wrong.
https://jsfiddle.net/he7oj42u/

Comment: `<span>`. Wrap your text in a `<span></span>` and provide the css class to that tag.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/he7oj42u/ - And this works. :( So, something must be wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Your second option should work, clean you cache and refresh the page again, it will work or change the browser

Comment: The style may be getting overridden by bootstrap. Check you web console to see.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue ended up being that since upgrading to VS 2015, my .less file wasn't being written to my css file, and the css file was never being updated. All fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

font-size: 200%;  changes the size of the font, it doesn't bold it.

Try instead

font-weight: bold;

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class directly on the div:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4 display_text">
    @Model.AccountNumber
</div>
```

If that's not working, make sure the property is not getting overridden by bootstrap. Your CSS strategy should have your custom CSS on top of bootstrap's.

Comment: This may be the issue, as my fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/he7oj42u/ Maybe something is overriding display_text.

Answer (score 0):

You should try css tag

> font-weight: bold;

```
<style>
.display_text{
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<span class="display_text">@Model.AccountNumber</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using two classes, col-xs-6 and col-lg-4?

Only second will be applied, use

```
<div class="col-lg-4 display_text">
    @Model.AccountNumber
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second option should work. clean you cache and refresh the page again, also check if you are adding external css. its path is right or not.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my .less file was not being copied to my .min.css file, due to a upgrade from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015. I noticed that in the console, the class was not displayed. I checked the .min.css and it didn't have the updated from the .less file.